# Android long update activity

Tags: android, database, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a button in my app which leads to the UpdateActivity. This activity doesn't show anything just a progress bar and there is an AsyncTask running with the updates.

The AsyncTask takes quite a long time because I conect to a server and retrieve info from many tables and inserting them in the sqlite database and sending data from local database to the server.

I am wondring if it's not better to use a service for this?? is it? On the other hand I have a doubt. When I press the back button I leave that activivty but the AsyncTask seems to be running in the back (because I have a toast to inform the user the job's done and it shows much later (even if I have left that activity!).

Then I have another activity which requires data to be read and written to/from the db so if I am doing that while another thread (the downloading thread) is messing up with the database too, is it possible that something goes wrong? Is there a way to prevent that? 
thanks in advance

Comment: too many questions dude, split them up and post some code samples for people to understand your real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your task in a service is defiantly a good idea for any long running operation that
will outlive your Activity.

At the moment your thread continues to run after leaving the activity,
but at any point that thread could be killed when the system kills the process.

Also presenting the user with UI from an Activity that has been and gone is not good for the UX.

The best thing to do is run your AsyncTask in a service and display status updates using a [status bar notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). This way the user can get an update of the progress as and
when they need to.
A service with a status notification is seen as long running and the system won't kill
the process (and therefore your thread) unless you are really low on memory.

As to the question of concurrent access to a database, you should probably write a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to control access to your database. ContentProviders must be
thread safe and will provide uniform access to your data within any part of your app
and can even be used by other apps should you wish to export your data.

Comment: Thanks I had a look it doesn't seem to simple but I will try. On the other hand if I have the db adapter defined like that: public class SqliteDataBaseAdapter implements Serializable {...} does it not prevent several instances?

Comment: [This](http://kagii.com/post/6828016869/android-sqlite-locking) link contains some info about SQLite locking in Android. It seems that there is Java locking implemented so you shouldn't get corruption.

Comment: @mcnicolsls: that link is great but there is some code with it to test the diferent scenarios but the link is broken. Any idea where I could get that code?

Comment: Yeah the link is broken and there is no contact information on his blog, but I did manage to track down a thread in the android-ndk mailing list where the author of the blog has posted. http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/7e8218f71eeaff46/2097df3c68177fd3. Maybe you can get his email address from there and contact him directly about the code.

Comment: thks I have sent an e-mail, will update here if I get something

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about the user making changes to the data while the sync is running, then making this a service won't really help you.   What you can do is kill the AsyncTask (gracefully) in the Activities onDestroy() method, so that if a user clicks the back arrow, the task won't continue to run.

Comment: well that what I was thinking but on the other hand if I kill the asynk task so maybe the data will be only half loaded/half updated. I just update all my tables one by one. So if the data have not been updated correctly it means the app is useless so I was wondering if there is a way to kind of prevent the user stopping the update half way trough.

Comment: Another thought is to prevent the user from being able to press the "back" button while the update is running.  You can do this by overriding the onBackPressed() method and throwing in some logic to tell it if the ProgressDialog is active or not.